How to define the docs _id when migrating to OpenSearch domain using AWS Glue?
I created an ETL job in AWS Glue to populate an index in an OpnSearch domain. I'm taking the data from the source(dynamodb table) and I'm applying some transformations before sending it to my index in the OpenSearch domain.
I ran the job and the _id is automatically created while inserting the data into OpenSearch. I would like to assign a value to this _id, it will be a unique identifier that have each resource across all resources.
I tried changing the schema to rename the identifier to _id but the job throws this error.
"Failure Reason": "Could not write all entries for bulk operation [1000/1000]. Error sample (first [5] error messages):\n\torg.opensearch.hadoop.rest.OpenSearchHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse field [_id] of type [_id] in document with id 'IiWP5pEBCVFWhBXaBFfm'. Preview of field's value: '21352';org.opensearch.hadoop.rest.OpenSearchHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters

Is it possible to assign the _id from AWS Glue or I'm wasting my time?

Prepare a column with the value you want to specify for _id (e.g. doc_id).
Next, enter opensearch.mapping.id as the key of the property in Data target, and put the column name you prepared above (doc_id) into the value.
In this way, you can specify the value of doc_id as _id.
By the way, this behavior works the same as upsert.
Hope this helps.
